# Send XML email as plain text with line break in Php

Tags: php, xml, email

I tried to send XML email as plain text with line break as follows.
But it is not working correctly.

```
$message = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\r\n".'
<?ADF VERSION="1.0"?> '."\r\n".'
<adf> '."\r\n".'
</adf> '."\r\n";

$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <Testing>'."\r\n";
mail('myemail@email.com', 'Subject', $message, $headers);
```

It is now sending emails properly but double line breaks.

Like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?ADF VERSION="1.0"?>

<adf>

</adf>
```

I want to send email like as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?ADF VERSION="1.0"?>
<adf>
</adf>
```

How can I do this?

Any help would appreciate.

Comment: let me know OS of your server

Comment: I already removed "\n" then it has no line break

Comment: It's best to use `PHP_EOL` instead of "\r\n". See: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php

Comment: You've got returns inside your strings. You start a string on one line, and then you jump to the next line (return) before you end the string.

Comment: Thanks but not working with PHP_EOL

Comment: Yes, `PHP_EOL` should not be used inside emails... it's the exception to the rule. :-) Emails are platform independent. See; https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822 p 2.2: "Header fields are lines composed of a field name, followed by a colon  (":"), followed by a field body, and terminated by CRLF".

Answer (score 0):

Combining my two comments, you could try this:

```
$message = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\r\n".
'<?ADF VERSION="1.0"?>'."\r\n".
'<adf>'."\r\n".
'</adf>'."\r\n";

$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <Testing>'."\r\n";
mail('myemail@email.com', 'Subject', $message, $headers);
```

EDIT: I was mistaken about the `PHP_EOL`. Emails are an exception, you should always use `"\r\n"`.

Comment: It is sending email without line break now

Comment: Ah, best use `"\r\n"` then, I'm not sure, but emails might be the exception where you shouldn't use the platform's line break.